# Load images from url stored in Firebase in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, imageview

I have a firebase database in which multiple urls of images are stored.
I have another activity in which i have to display all the images in imageview.

```
String temp = postSnapshot.getValue().toString();                  
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(temp).fit().centerCrop().into(mImageView);
```

In the above way i am fetching the data but only one image url is fetched and displayed in imageview.How to do this for all the images.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a listview or a RecyclerView,

An [example](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/pinterest-masonry-layout-staggered-grid/).

Then populate each one.

See my implementation here: [Github](https://github.com/Galeaettu/GlobalNode/blob/master/app/src/main/java/a100588/galea/christian/globalnodes/ChatActivity.java#L459:L4961)

Comment: Will it load the same image again and again?How to move to next entry in database.

Comment: `FirebaseListAdapter` has an override method called `populateView` which will go to each position. see l[line 456](https://github.com/Galeaettu/GlobalNode/blob/master/app/src/main/java/a100588/galea/christian/globalnodes/ChatActivity.java#L456)

Comment: You need to have a list view or something else which iterates through values and displays them.